# Convert table to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table

I'm somewhat of a JavaScript noob, so the solution to this may be more basic than I realize.  I'm trying to grab data from this table and display it in an array. The table starts as follows:

```
<table id="myTable">
     <col>
        <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Results1</th>
                <th>Results2</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td>Jan-00</td>
                <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Feb-00</td>
                <td>92</td>
                <td>64</td>
             </tr>
```

And goes on from there (it's a long table with a lot of `<tr>`'s).

My code to grab the variables starts as the following (hat-tip to other sources for helping me out with this):

```
var columns = $('#myTable thead th').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    });
    var tableObject = $('#myTable tr').map(function(i) {
        var row = {};
        // Find all of the table cells on this row.
        $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
        // Determine the cell's column name by comparing its index
        //  within the row with the columns list we built previously.
        var rowName = columns[i];
        // Add a new property to the row object, using this cell's
        //  column name as the key and the cell's text as the value.
            row[rowName] = $(this).text();
        });
        // Return the row's object representation, to be included
        //  in the array that $.map() ultimately returns.
        return row;
        // .get() to convert the jQuery set to a regular array.
        }).get();
        for (var i in tableObject) {
            $.each(tableObject[i], function(key,value) { 
                var line1 = {};
                line1[key] = value;
                console.log(line1); //test
            });
        }
```

In the console.log test, the variable line1 now shows its holding keys and values like the following: Date: Jan 00, Results1:9, Results2:10.

That's all well and good, but I really need to get these values into a new array in the following format:

```
var new = [[Date, Results1], [Date, Results2], etc...];
```

Apologies if I'm repeating a question, but couldn't find quite what I was looking for. Really appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over an array, and there's no need to use `$.each()` inside of that loop.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var ary = [];
$('tr').each(function() {
    date = $('td:first', this).text();
    $('td:gt(0)', this).each(function() {
        ary.push([date, $(this).text()]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, though I am still unpacking how it works. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Basically it traverses the table rows, stores the value of the first cell as the date, and then traverses the remaining cells in the row, adding the date/value pair to an array as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp 
i would suggest using the *tableObject*.rows to get an array of rows with the cells in it. then use the *rows*.cells to get all the cell elements. 
it could look something like

```
   var table =document.getElementById("myTable")
  var foo = new array(table.rows.length);
  for(var j =0; j<foo.length; j++)
   foo[j]=foo[j].cells;
```

this will give you the table into a 2d array called foo. that is represneted in the form
foo[rowindex][col/cellindex]
(ie foo[0][1] will return Results 1;

hope this can get you started

Comment: Thanks GreenGiant. I'll look into this as a potentially more efficient solution as well.